# MudBlazor remove top margin after deleting AppBar?

Tags: mudblazor

I created a MudBlazor template project. The top "AppBar" seemed unnecessary and taking place, so I deleted it. The problem is that page content is still placed below that area as if AppBar is there. How can I remove that margin?

```
<MudLayout>
@*    <MudAppBar Elevation="0">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor" Color="Color.Inherit" Link="https://mudblazor.com/" Target="_blank" />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.GitHub" Color="Color.Inherit" Link="https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/" Target="_blank" />
    </MudAppBar>*@
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" Elevation="1">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">MudBlazorTemplates1</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        @*<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">*@
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The source of the margin is top padding on the MudMainContent component in your layout.  You can remove the margin by removing that padding.

Something like this will do it:

```
    <MudMainContent Style="padding-top: 0;">
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
```

Anything that removes the padding will work, whether that is style text as above, a css class, JavaScript, or Razor/C# code that conditionally applies one of the above strategies.